# Using user input value of unsigned char instead of the generated value behind the unsigned char

Tags: c

I have an algorithm which works perfectly with `int` but my input needs to be an unsigned char:

```
unsigned char a;

printf("a:");
scanf("%c",&a);
```

and because of this the algorithm doesn't take the Input 4 as 4 but instead 52 (ASCII).
So my question: is there a way I can use the input 4 as a 4 in my calculations without changing the `%c` in the input code?

Comment: Is the input number always just one digit? If so, then `a -= '0';` after the `scanf` will turn '4' into 4.

Comment: If you wanted a solution “without changing the input code,” why did you accept the solution that changed the code the most?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Or if you insist to use `%c`

```
    unsigned char x,y;
    const char digits[] = "0123456789";

    x = scanf("%c", &x) == 1 ? x - '0' : -1;  //<-- less portable and no check 
 
    y = scanf("%c", &y) == 1 ? (isdigit(y) ? (strchr(digits, y) - digits) : -1 ): -1;
    //^^^^ a bit more portable and more checks
```

Comment: Aside: `y - '0'` is portable and simpler than `strchr(digits, y) - digits` as C requires the 10 digits to be in ascending order.

Answer (score 3):

Since C99, use — *length modifier* `"hh"`.

```
scanf("%hhu",&a);
```

Pre C-99, read via an `unsigned`

```
unsigned u;
scanf("%u",&u);
a = u;
```

Answer (score 2):

Change `scanf("%c",&a);` to `scanf("%hhu",&a);`.